# How to not output anything when the first command of a pipe does not output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe

I have 2 commands which I want to pipe like so: `command1 | command2`. When `command1` does not output anything at all `command2` still outputs. How do I stop 
`command1 | command2` from outputting when `command1` does not output anything?

Concrete example:

```
function find_string_in_file {
find . -iname "*$1*" | xargs ack-grep "$2"
}
alias findag='find_string_in_file'
```

If `filename.py` does not exist in the current directory or its subfolders then `findag filename.py "some word"` still returns the same output as `ack-grep "some word"`.

Comment: You could use `ack-grep` like `ack-grep "some word" *filename.py*`, but of course the file match won't be case-insensitive

Comment: To clarify your question, it is not really about arranging for the second command to "not output anything" when the first command produces no results, it's about not running the second command at all in that situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipes are not conditional, so you can't disable later stages based on the exit status of previous stages. For your particular example, you can modify the `find` command to avoid the need for a pipeline.

```
find . -iname "*$1*" -exec ack-grep "$2" '{}' +
```

If there are no matching files, the `exec` test won't be triggered.

Comment: Or you could just use `xargs`'s `-r` option in order to retain the efficiency of using `xargs` over `find -exec` which runs the command once per file found.

Answer (score 1):

You can change how you use `xargs` to require `ack-grep` to read arguments in line instead of through the pipe.  This will work as you expect

```
find . -iname "*$1*" | xargs -I{} ack-grep "$2" {}
```

Comment: I believe this will cause `ack-grep` to be invoked once per file found by `find`. That can get unnecessarily expensive if there are a lot of matches.